# Firebase Database recyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, firebase

Немного глупый вопрос но все же.
Имеется простенькое приложение которое выводит список из базы ФайрБэйс.
Все туториалы построены в основном потоке. 
Насколько это правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Firebase Database все действия по дефолту асинхронны, следовательно заморозки UI при работе с Firebase быть не должно.

P.S. А вопрос не глупый, тоже в свое время им задался:)